# Object reference not set to an instance when modifying an existing cookie in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the line "Response.Cookies...", I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is there a way to fix this and use a timer in my ASPX code behind?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    object o = new object();

    TimerCallback timercallback = new TimerCallback(StartCallback);

    System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(timercallback, o, 0, 50000);



    if (are.WaitOne())
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}


public void StartCallback(object o)
{
    //Request.Cookies["haspassed?"].Value = "";

    Response.Cookies["haspassed?"].Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

    are.Set();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use a timer here? Shouldn't you be looking for a client-side script?

Comment: Server cookies can be more tightly controlled than client coding permits.

Answer (score 2):

iirc the new thread which StartCallback is going to operate in isn't going to have an HTTPContext, so the nullpointer is that Response does not exist. Why not pass it the context as "o"?

Comment: I wondered about that - but I believe Response is just a reference within the Page. (It's not like HttpContext.Current.)

Comment: I don't think that's the case. There's a public HttpRequest Request { get; } on the Page class, but I can't imagine how that can point at *this* request context within another thread. Easy to test though, put a breakpoint on it and see what's null :)

Comment: Actually since Page is an IHttpHandler with it's own Context property I think it's probably *exactly* like HttpContext.Current...

Answer (score 1):

So I cast o to a HttpContext object? I'll give that a go.

I'm using a C# timer out of preference of server side coding than JS, really.

Comment: A). you should post this as a comment not an additional answer if possible, B). yes, but of course remember to pass it in as well, and C). I think the question is why are you doing this in a timer at all, you could be setting it in the page_load. What's the gain?

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd problem; `Response` (according to Reflector) is:

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public HttpResponse Response
{
    get
    {
        if (this._response == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Response_not_available"));
        }
        return this._response;
    }
}
```

So it can't return null - you'd get an `HttpException` instead.

Likewise, `Cookies` is:

```
public HttpCookieCollection Cookies
{
    get
    {
        if (this._cookies == null)
        {
            this._cookies = new HttpCookieCollection(this, false);
        }
        return this._cookies;
    }
}
```

So you wouldn't get null there either.

The `Cookies`' indexer? Nope:

```
public HttpCookie Get(string name)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = (HttpCookie) base.BaseGet(name);
    if ((cookie == null) && (this._response != null))
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
        this.AddCookie(cookie, true);
        this._response.OnCookieAdd(cookie);
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

So I thought, the only thing we have left, is inside the `Cookies` indexer, if `this._response == null`, the cookie setting will not happen and this will return `null`. But that can't happen either since `_cookies` is only ever in that line we saw earlier, which calls a constructor which is the only place where `_response` is set - set to the correct `HttpRespones`, never `null`.

In conclusion, I've dug deep in there and can't see any way for the `Response.Cookies["haspassed?"].Expires` setter to ever throw a `NullReferenceException`.